# After a few GUI switches my program no longer opens the next GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Goal: I'm making a calculator for a class using python, this calculator is different as it allows you to also do several different types of conversions (temp, weight, length). Each of these has their own Gui.

Problem: I just started learning python 4 weeks ago and to simplify switching between my Gui's I simply implemented a function which uses .destroy() to close the window and then import to open up the Gui that needs to be opened. While testing switching back and forth on the third switch no matter which gui I'm on, it closes the window but doesn't open the gui I wish to switch to. there are also no errors being thrown and it opens all the gui's correctly first time around.

Main Menu

```
from tkinter import *
#this is main menu py
def toNextGui():
    gui.destroy()
    import nextGui

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")
guiBTN = Button(gui, text="next gui", command = toNextGui).pack()
gui.mainloop()
```

Next GUI

```
from tkinter import *
def toMainMenu():
    gui.destroy()
    import mm

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")
guiBTN = Button(gui, text="main menu", command = toMainMenu).pack()
gui.mainloop()
```

Note: I know I have not posted much code as I do not wish to be hit with a plagiarism infraction

Comment: There's no way we can reproduce this problem with so little code. Please create a [mcve] that we can use to understand the problem.

Comment: `import` only actually executes the code in a module *once* - after that, it just returns the existing module object.  To make a reusable piece of code, you need to put it in a function definition, and call that function each time.

Comment: @BryanOakley I editted it

Comment: Aside from the module import issue mentioned above, have a look at [the Notebook widget](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Notebook.html).